# JQuery DataTable resets on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, datatables, click

I am using jQuery DataTables on a site that features the regular searchbox and some preset buttons that sort the table by column when pressed.  The code does indeed sort the table when the button resets, but it immediately resets within 1/2 second. Here is my code:

```
//CATEGORY BUTTONS
        $("#Term").on('click', function (event) {
            dataTable.column(2).search('Term').draw();

        });
```

I've searched around and looked at many forums.  This should be correct, but the result always instantly resets the form.  I've removed the search box functionality to see if that was interfering and causing the issue, but the issue remained.  It just blinks the results up really fast and then resets it all to showing the entire list again. Could this be a thing with Internet Explorer (this machine has no access to any other browsers)?

Here is the full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        //USES API FOR DYNAMIC SEARCHING
        //RENDERS TABLE
        var dataTable = $("#videos").DataTable({
            "paging": false,
            bjQueryUI: true,
            ajax: {
                url: "/api/videos",
                dataSrc: ""
            },
            columns: [
                {
                    width: "70%",
                    data: "title",
                    render: function (data, type, video) {
                        var videoTitle = video.title.toUpperCase();
                        return "<VideoItem><a href='" + "../" + video.url + "'>" + "<spacerTop>" + videoTitle + "</spacerTop></a></VideoItem>";
                    }
                },
                {
                    width: "10%",
                    visible: false,
                    data: "description",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    width: "10%",
                    visible: false,
                    data: "categoryName",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    width: "10%",
                    visible: false,
                    data: "meta",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    width: "10%",
                    visible: false,
                    data: "date",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                },
                {
                    width: "10%",
                    visible: false,
                    data: "categoryID",
                    render: function (data) {
                        return data;
                    }
                }

            ]


        });


        //CONTROLS DELETE BUTTON ACTION
        $("#videos").on("click", ".js-delete", function () {
            var button = $(this);

            bootbox.confirm("Are your sure you want to delete this video?", function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/api/videos/" + button.attr("data-video-id"),
                        method: "DELETE",
                        success: function () {
                            button.parents("tr").remove();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });

        });

        //MAKES SEARCH BOX ON TOP INTERACT WITH DATATABLE
        $(".search-box-input").keyup(function () {
            dataTable.search(this.value).draw();
        });

        //CATEGORY BUTTONS
        $("#Term").on('click', function (event) {
            dataTable.column(2).search('Term').draw();

        });


    });
```

Comment: is it possible that the `#Term` button is causing the page to refresh? Try adding `event.preventDefault()` to the button click event.

Comment: Hours of tearing my hair out solved!!! That was it!

Comment: <button> by default is a submit button so you have to add type="button" if you don't want it to be